# Left join and indicator matching

Tags: sql, left-join, matching, indicator

So I am new to sql and I need some coding assistance.
Here are my tables

```
   Table_A      
Customer ID_2019    
   A       600  
   A       697
   A       932  



   Table_B      
Customer ID_2018    
   A       600  
   A       697
```

Here is the code when I merge the two tables together
--Merge the results together

```
select a.*,b.id_2018 into #temp
from Table_A as a left join Table_B as b
on a.customer=b.customer;
```

Here are my results:

```
Results 
Customer ID_2019  ID_2018
918      600        600
918      600        697
918      697        600
918      697        697
918      932        600
918      932        697

Here are the results that I desire:
--Desired Results       
Customer   ID_2019  ID_2018
918          600     600
918          697     697
918          932      -
```

I would like to merge the customer's ID_2019 and ID_2018 together; For the third ID_2019 (932), I would like the ID_2018 to have a blank or a dash.

--I would like to put an indicator on there to see if ID_2019 matches ID_2018 and create a new variable with a 1 or 0.

```
--drop table #match_nomatch;
select *,
case when ID_2019=ID_2018 then 1 else 0 end as Match into #Match_NoMatch
from #temp
group by customer, ID_2019, ID_2018;
```

Here are my results:

```
--The results for ID_2018 are repeating the same 2 id's over again  
Customer  ID_2019   ID_2018 Match
918         600      600    1
918         600      697    0
918         697      600    0
918         697      697    1
918         932      600    0
918         932      697    0
```

Here are my desired results:

```
Desired Results         
Customer ID_2019    ID_2018 Match
918      600         600    1
918      697         697    1
918      932           -    0
```

For the code above, if ID_2019 and ID_2018 matches, put a 1, else 0. Again for the third Id_2019, I would like the ID_2018 to be blank or a dash.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if id_2019 is not present but id_2018 is present? Do you want all ids of 2019 only in the result?

Comment: No. I would like blanks or dashes if the information is not present either in ID_2018 or ID_2019.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `full outer join` using the `customer, id_2018 and id_2019` as follows:

```
select coalesce(a.customer,b.customer) as customer, 
       a.id_2019, b.id_2018 
  into #temp
  from Table_A as a full join Table_B as b
    on a.customer=b.customer and a.id_2019 = b.id_2018;
```

Comment: Yes! This is awesome! Thank you.

Comment: You can accept the answer which you think is correct so that this question is marked as resolved

Answer (score 0):

You need a column for the join to assign the row number.  You don't have one so you can invent one:

```
select a.*, b.id_2018
into #temp
from (select a.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from Table_A a
     ) a left join
     (select b.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from Table_B b
     ) b
     on a.customer = b.customer and a.seqnum = b.seqnum;
```